# Javascript on click event not reading else statement or variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, scope, closures

I'm trying to make a click handler that calls a function; and that function gets a string and basically slices the last character and adds it to the front, and each time you click again it should add the last letter to the front.

It seem so easy at first that I thought I could just do it using array methods.

```
 function scrollString() {

    var defaultString = "Learning to Code Javascript Rocks!";
    var clickCount = 0;

    if (clickCount === 0) {
        var stringArray = defaultString.split("");
        var lastChar = stringArray.pop();
        stringArray.unshift(lastChar);
        var newString = stringArray.join('');
        clickCount++;

    } else {
        var newArray = newString.split("");
        var newLastChar = newArray.pop();
        newArray.unshift(newLastChar);
        var newerString = newArray.join("");
        clickCount++;
    }

    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = (clickCount === 1) ? newString : newerString;

}

$('#button').on('click', scrollString);
```

Right now it only works the first time I click, and developer tools says newArray is undefined; also the clickCount stops incrementing. I do not know if it's an issue of scope, or should I take a whole different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click you are actually reseting the string. Check the scope!

```js
var str = "Learning to Code Javascript Rocks!";
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var output = document.getElementById("output");


output.innerHTML = str;

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 str = str.charAt(str.length - 1) + str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  output.innerHTML = str;
});
```

```css
button{
    display: block;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>

<label id="output"></label>
```

Comment: This answer is much better than mine. Take an upvote. I was too lazy to actually do this part of it. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!

Comment: So simple dude, thanks....I think I overthought the process since I'm still learning to code  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is, in fact, a scoping issue. Your counter in inside the function, so each time the function is called, it gets set to 0. If you want a counter that is outside of the scope, and actually keeps a proper count, you will need to abstract it from the function.

If you want to keep it simple, even just moving clickCount above the function should work.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know if it's an issue of scope

Yes, it is an issue of scope, more than one actually.

**How?**

1. As pointed out by @thesublimeobject, the counter is inside the function and hence gets reinitialized every time a click event occurs.
2. Even if you put the counter outside the function, you will still face another scope issue. In the `else` part of the function, you are manipulation a variable (`newString`) you initialized inside the `if` snippet. Since, the `if` snippet didn't run this time, it will throw the error `undefined`. (again a scope issue)

A fine approach would be:

1. take the counter and the `defaultString` outside the function. If the `defaultString` gets a value dynamically rather than what you showed in your code, extract its value on page load or any other event like `change`, etc. rather than passing it inside the function.
2. Do not assign a new string the result of your manipulation. Instead, assign it to `defaultString`. This way you probably won't need an `if-else` loop and a `newLastChar` to take care of newer results.
3. Manipulate the assignment to the element accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript closure functionality.

```
var scrollString = (function() {
var defaultString = "Learning to Code Javascript Rocks!";
return function() {
    // convert the string into array, so that you can use the splice method
    defaultString = defaultString.split('');

    // get last element
    var lastElm = defaultString.splice(defaultString.length - 1, defaultString.length)[0];

    // insert last element at start
    defaultString.splice(0, 0, lastElm);

    // again join the string to make it string
    defaultString = defaultString.join('');
    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = defaultString;
    return defaultString;
}
})();
```

Using this you don't need to declare any variable globally, or any counter element.

To understand Javascript Closures, please refer this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: Genius....I did wanted to use closures but I didn't know how to implement a solution; I appreciate your help... xD